# Laravel 4 mass assignment guarded not work

Tags: php, laravel, mass-assignment

I wonder what wrong in my code that I can't protected 2 input username and password

In my controller:

```
class AccountsController extends \BaseController {

...

public function store()
    {
        $date = new \DateTime;
        $input['updated_at']=$date;
        $input['created_at']=$date;
        $input['username']=Input::get("username", "");
        $input['password']=Input::get("password", "");
        $input['sex']=Input::get("sex", "");
        $input['dob']=Input::get("dob", "");
        $input['dob']= date("Y-m-d", strtotime($input['dob']));

        $v=Validator::make($input, Account::$register_rules);
        $input['password']=Hash::make($input['password']);
        if($v->passes()){
            DB::table('accounts')->insert($input);

        }
        //return Redirect::route('text.index');
    }

...

}
```

In my model:

```
class Account extends \Eloquent {
    protected $guarded = array('username', 'password');

    public static $register_rules=array(
                'username'   => 'required|min:4|max:20|unique:accounts',
                'password'   => 'required|alpha_num|min:6',
                'sex'       =>  'required|in:f,m',
                'dob'       => 'required|date_format:Y-m-d'
            );
}
```

In my app/view

```
...


{{ Form::open(array('route'=>'account.store')) }}
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <td>{{ Form::label('username', 'Username') }}</td>
                    <td>{{ Form::text('username') }}</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>{{ Form::label('password', 'Password') }}</td>
                    <td>{{ Form::password('password') }}</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>{{ Form::label('confirm_password', 'Confirm Password') }}</td>
                    <td>{{ Form::password('confirm_password', array('id'=>'confirm_password')) }}</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>{{ Form::label('sex', 'Sex') }}</td>
                    <td>
                        {{ Form::radio('sex', 'f', true) }}{{ Form::label('Female') }}
                        {{ Form::radio('sex', 'm') }}{{ Form::label('Male') }}
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>{{ Form::label('dob', 'Date of Birth') }}</td>
                    <td>
                        {{Form::text('dob', '', array('id' => 'dob'))}}
                    </td>
                </tr>

                <tr>
                    <td></td>
                    <td>{{ Form::submit('Register', array('id' => 'submit')) }}</td>
                </tr>

            </table>
        {{ Form::close() }}

...
```

Even though I defined guarded these two fields they are still saved in the database.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually you are not using `Eloquent ORM` and hence the following code guards mass assignment of `Eloquent` models, for example using `Model::create(Input::all())` method you may create a new `Account` in the database like:

```
$account = Account::create(Input::all());
```

In your case, you are not using `Eloquent` model, instead you are using `insert` method using `DB::('accounts')->insert($input)` which is a feature of `Query builder` class (It's an instance of `Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder`).

So, if you use the `Eloquent ORM` then the features of `Eloquent` will be used. In this case, use of `Model::save()` is not a mass assignment but `create()` uses the mass assignment because when creating a new model, you may pass an `array` of attributes to the model constructor. These attributes are then assigned to the model via mass-assignment and `create` accepts an `array` of attributes and then initializes the model using `new static($attributes)`, for example, this is the `create` method:

```
public static function create(array $attributes)
{
    $model = new static($attributes);
    $model->save();
    return $model;
}
```

So, if you manually initiate a model using something like this:

```
$account = new Account(Input::all()); // Mass assignment through constructor
$account->save();
```

This will be a mass assignment. In this case you need to create the `Account` model by extending the `Eloquent` like this (You already have one):

```
class Account extends Eloquent {

    // Protect mass assignment
    protected $guarded = array('username', 'password');

    //...
}
```

You may read more about [Mass Assignment](http://laravel.com/docs/eloquent#mass-assignment) on `Laravel` website.

Comment: Thanks you. Your answer is also perfect. Actually Thank you for your reference link now. I suppose that DB:: worked with Eloquent but not. I can't vote up your answer because i score is too low sorry :)

Comment: Glad it was helpful and regarding voting up, you can't up vote but you can accept my answer by clicking on the tick (make it green to accept) and you can accept only one answer per question :-)

Answer (score 1):

You are not using the Eloquent ORM. If you don't use the ORM you can't expect any of its features to be used.

```
DB::table('accounts')->insert($input);
```

Should be

```
$account = new Account($input);
$account->save():
// This is mass assigning model attributes
```

Now you will see that your guarded attributes are properly guarded. It is recommended that you do not pass raw input data into a model that has guarded attributes set without defining them either as fillable or making sure you specifically sanitise the data.

So your code would become something similar to the below.

```
$model = new Account();

$model->username = Input::get('username', '');
//  etc ...

$validator = Validator::make($model->toArray(), $rules);

if ( ! $validator->fails() )
    $model->save();
```

Comment: This `Account::save()` is not a `mass assignment` and you can't do it like `Account::save(Input::all())`. Check my answer.

Comment: You're correct, not sure what I was thinking when I wrote that. Corrected

Comment: Wow it worked. I like your clear answer. I just changed as you you said and it is what i want. thanks you so much I want to vote your answer up but my score is too low sorry..